# Executing script on device shutdown

Tags: customization, scripts, shutdown

For custom scripts at boot, we have `init.d`. I want to know if there's a possibility of executing a custom script when shutting down, something similar to `init.d` or by using an APK?

Comment: You could make an app that receives the SHUTDOWN intent.

Comment: I think you can create a xposed framework module for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Our default answer on questions like this is [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker) – whenever it comes to [automation](/questions/tagged/automation), this is the most powerful tool to be mentioned. *Tasker* combines *Contexts* (Events, states, location, time) with *Tasks* to be fired when such a context is met. For your case, there's an event called *Device Shutdown* – which you could combine with the task *Code › Run Shell* to execute your shutdown scripts.

For further reading, I strongly recommend you visiting our [tasker tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info), which also links to additional resources like the [tasker user-guide](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/) or my [collection of tasker resources](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_tasker).

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy. especially for scripts that have to run after zygote was stopped. Try to digg `/*.rc` scripts. may be attaching to the `swapoff` action help you. There are some mod projects at xda too https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1387692